# Woocommerce Single product content featured image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to switch woocommerce single product featured image to be the main content area. My website displays the featured image on the single product section but I would prefer to replace that with my main content where I am using an iFrame animation.

I am assuming the files that needs to be changed are: content-single-product.php - woocommerce-hooks.php and product-image.php - On my content single product I have the following code:

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_single_product hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_show_messages - 10
     */
     do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product' );
?>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_show_product_images hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_images - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );
    ?>

    <div class="summary entry-summary">

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
        ?>

    </div><!-- .summary -->

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_single_product_summary hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
    ?>
```

Should I replace:  `* @hooked woocommerce_show_product_images` - 20 and replace that with `@hooked woocommerce_show_product_main_content` ?

Sorry I am a beginner,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want featured image then you should write in your functions.php file:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
```

and add your own action that output's content
you can create hook that calls your own template file with content you need
woocommerce have function like

```
woocommerce_get_template('single-product/your-content.php');
```